# How can I combine an identity predicate with first-order predicates while using FindEquationalProof

Tags: logic, theorem-proving

I am trying out some of the automated theorem proving in mathematica, and for my test case am working with Tarski and Sczerba's (mostly) first-order axiomatization of Affine Geometry, which has just one non-logical "betweenness" predicate between points. The solver works fine for many cases; for instance, when I give it the statements

```
innertransitivity = 
 ForAll[{x, y, w, z}, 
  Implies[bet[x, y, w] && bet[y, z, w], bet[x, y, z]]]

symmetry = ForAll[{x, y, z}, Implies[bet[x, y, z], bet[z, y, x]]]

innertransitivityS = 
 ForAll[{x, y, w, z}, 
  Implies[bet[w, y, x] && bet[w, z, y], bet[z, y, x]]]
```

and ask it to find a proof object for the third it spits one out right away. But when I try to mix in any axioms that also use identity, such as

```
identy = ForAll[{x, y}, Implies[bet[x, y, x], x == y]]
```

I get an "invalid specification of propositions" error.

I'm pretty sure what's happening is that the system's translation into equational logic is choking on what's essentially a clash of types, because it's turning all my predicates into objects and the operators (`Implies' and so on) into something equational.

For the record, I've tried replacing predicates with functional identities (replacing `bet[x,y,z]` with `bet[x,y,z]==True`, for instance) to no avail; it's a clash with the logic operators that are causing a problem.

What I'm wondering is if there is either (i) a "predicate-logic" version of an identity predicate that I could use in these formulas that wouldn't cause a translation crash, or (ii) a pre-established set of logic functions I could use to "equationalize" my first-order formulas. (I'd prefer the first, in large part because the second will have to involve separating out the first-order domain from the "equational" domain of truth-evaluable objects, or at least hoping one embeds into the other.) I haven't been able to find anything useful in the documentation, so I turn here for help.

*Edited to add:* I get the error when I combine the above inputs with
`FindEquationalProof[identy,identy]`

To reproduce a simple version use
`FindEquationalProof[ForAll[x,Implies[F[x],F[x]]],ForAll[x,x==x]]`
which delivers the error

> Invalid specification of propositions True and axioms True.

Comment: Can you put the `Resolve` or `FindEquationalProof` code in your question too? Nothing here is producing an error otherwise.